# Detecting an image upload/capture event on mobile with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, event-handling, image-uploading, onchange

I'm attempting to capture an image with a mobile device and then do some logic with the file. I have it working fine on desktop but the change event doesn't seem to be firing on mobile (only tested with IOS).

I'm using a custom directive to listen for the change event since you cannot use ng-model on a file input.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" file-change="getFile">
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller("pageCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.getFile = function (e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0]
    };
}]);
```

My file-change directive:

```
app.directive('fileChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.fileChange);
            element.on('change', function (e) {
                // never reaches this point on mobile devices
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    onChangeHandler(e);
                })
            });

            element.on('$destroy', function() {
                element.off();
            });
        }
    };
});
```